# Visual Studio 2010 builds excluded files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have some excluded files in a web application project.

One developer's machine builds the project fine.

Another developer's machine sees the excluded files and decides to compile them, therefore throwing compilation errors related to those files.

Both are using VS2010 SP1.

I am not aware of any compilation options that could cause this difference.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  My VS2010 is including a bunch of "excluded" folders and files every time I publish. I don't understand why, since everything I keep reading says this isn't supposed to happen. Checking the "properties" on these excluded files and folders in this VS project (after pushing-in the solution explorer's `Show All Files` button, of course) does not reveal anything that might explain this. Nor can I find any settings in the project properties such as "include excluded files and folders when you publish?" Because this is certainly not the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

Do they both share the same `.sln` and `.csproj` file? (assuming its a c# project).

There is a compile `cs` content flag which can be set on files (right click on the file and select properties).  Possibly one has one set on one machine, and the other dev has it set differently on a different machine.

Another issue (assuming its not just standard `.cs` code) is that there's a custom tool which is used for compilation. For example DevArt `Entity Designer` uses `.edml` extensions. If the tool isn't installed it just treats these files as content, if the tool is installed treats them as compilable/generatable.

Comment: yes, same solution/project files.  both freshly pulled from source control.  it's puzzling...

Comment: no custom generators on those files.  most are just .aspx or .cs files in the views or controllers folder (it's and ASP.NET MVC web project), i'll check their VS plugins to see if there's something that can change the compiler.

Comment: Doesn't need to be plugins, I believe it can be external tools.